# Simple oscillator displacement, speed, and acceleration diagram

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator

I'm currently studying the textbook *Fundamentals of Acoustics* (2000) by Kinsler et al. Chapter **1.2 The Simple Oscillator** says the following:

> $$\dfrac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + \omega_0^2 x = 0 \tag{1.2.5}$$
> This is an important linear differential equation whose general solution is well known and may be obtained by several methods.
> One method is to assume a trial solution of the form
> $$x = A_1 \cos(\gamma t) \tag{1.2.6}$$
> Differentiation and substitution into (1.2.5) shows that this is a solution if $\gamma = \omega_0$. It may similarly be shown that
> $$x = A_2 \sin(\omega_0 t) \tag{1.2.7}$$
> is also a solution. The complete general solution is the sum of these two,
> $$x = A_1 \cos(\omega_0 t) + A_2 \sin(\omega_0 t) \tag{1.2.8}$$
> where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are arbitrary constants and the parameter $\omega_0$ is the *natural angular frequency* in radians per second (rad/s).

Chapter **1.3 Initial Conditions** says the following:

> If at time $t = 0$ the mass has an initial displacement $x_0$ and an initial speed $u_0$, then the arbitrary constants $A_1$ and $A_2$ are fixed by these initial conditions and the subsequent motion of the mass is completely determined. Direct substitution into (1.2.8) of $x = x_0$ at $t = 0$ will show that $A_1$ equals the initial displacement $x_0$.  Differentiation of (1.2.8) and substitution of the initial speed at $t = 0$ gives $u_0 = \omega_0 A_2$, and (1.2.8) becomes
> $$x = x_0 \cos(\omega_0 t) + (u_0/\omega_0) \sin(\omega_0 t) \tag{1.3.1}$$
> Another form of (1.2.8) may be obtained by letting $A_1 = A\cos(\phi)$ and $A_2 = -A\sin(\phi)$, where $A$ and $\phi$ are two new arbitrary constants. Substitution and simplification then gives
> $$x = A\cos(\omega_0 t + \phi) \tag{1.3.2}$$
> where $A$ is the *amplitude* of the motion and $\phi$ is the *initial phase angle* of the motion. The values of $A$ and $\phi$ are determined by the initial conditions and are
> $$A = [x_0^2 + (u_0/\omega_0)^2]^{1/2} \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ \ \phi = \tan^{-1}(-u_0/\omega_0 x_0) \tag{1.3.3}$$
> Successive differentiation of (1.3.2) shows that the speed of the mass is
> $$u = -U \sin(\omega_0 t + \phi) \tag{1.3.4}$$
> where $U = \omega_0 A$ is the *speed amplitude*, and the acceleration of the mass is
> $$a = - \omega_0 U \cos(\omega_0 t + \phi) \tag{1.3.5}$$
> In these forms it is seen that the displacement lags $90^\circ$ ($\pi/2$ rad) behind the speed and that the acceleration is $180^\circ$ ($\pi$ rad) out of phase with the displacement, as shown in Fig. 1.3.1.
> [image]

*(Arrows in figure 1.3.1 are mine.)*

We can see from figure 1.3.1 that the displacement is out of phase with the acceleration by $\pi$ radians (green arrow), as stated, but it seems to me that, according to figure 1.3.1, displacement is actually $3\pi/2$ radians out of phase with speed (blue arrow), rather than the stated $\pi/2$ radians (red arrow). Is this an error, or am I misunderstanding this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express displacement $x$, speed $u$, and acceleration $a$ via the same trigonometric function with positive amplitude:

$$x(t) = A \cos (\omega_0 t + \phi) = A \sin (\omega_0 t + \phi + \frac{\pi}{2})$$

$$u(t) = - \omega_0 A \sin(\omega_0 t + \phi) = \omega_0 A \sin(\omega_0 t + \phi + \pi)$$

$$a(t) = -\omega_0^2 A \cos(\omega_0 t + \phi) = \omega_0^2 A \sin(\omega_0 t + \phi - \frac{\pi}{2})$$

Note that if we used $\cos$ instead of $\sin$, the final result would have been the same.

From the three equations above, the phase difference of:

- acceleration to displacement is $-\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2} = -\pi = \pi$
- acceleration to speed is $-\frac{\pi}{2} - \pi = -\frac{3\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$
- displacement to speed is $\frac{\pi}{2} - \pi = -\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{3\pi}{2}$

From the graph, by looking at positive to negative transition points, the phase difference of:

- acceleration to displacement is $\frac{3\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2} = \pi = -\pi$
- acceleration to speed is $\frac{3\pi}{2} - 2\pi = -\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{3\pi}{2}$
- displacement to speed is $\frac{\pi}{2} - 2\pi = -\frac{3\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$

You can see that acceleration-speed phase difference for the two methods above is off by a factor $\pi$. (The same applies to the displacement-speed phase difference.) Note that I did this on purpose! The catch is in the convention you use, i.e. which angle comes first in the angle difference. **It does not matter which convention you use as long as you stick to one convention!** This means acceleration-speed phase difference of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is valid only if displacement-speed phase difference is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, which is also clear from the acceleration-displacement phase difference.

You can read the above results as follows:

- acceleration leads speed by $\frac{\pi}{2}$, or acceleration lags speed by $\frac{3\pi}{2} = -\frac{\pi}{2}$
- displacement leads speed by $\frac{3\pi}{2} = -\frac{\pi}{2}$, or displacement lags speed by $\frac{\pi}{2}$

To see this side-by-side, acceleration and displacement

- lead speed by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, respectively;
- lag speed by $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$, respectively.

Answer (score 7):

Note that in the diagram below the velocity **leads** the displacement by $\dfrac \pi 2$ which is the same as the velocity **lagging** the displacement by $\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$.

[image]

So when mentioning phase it is important to state which two quantities are being compared, eg $A$ and $B$, and then whether there is a lead or lag between them, eg $A$ leads/lags $B$.

$A$ **leading** $B$ by $\phi$ is the same as $A$ **lagging** $B$ by $2\pi -\phi$.

Comment: The caption says that the speed "leads to" the displacement - presumably this is an editing mistake in the book and it should just read "...always leads the displacement by 90°".